# Geodjango ... ImportError: No module named apps.AdminConfig

Tags: django, geodjango

I have no idea why the app is crashing when I try to run:

```
python manage.py sqlall world
```

I am taking the django tutorial for geodjango, and my settings contain:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin.apps.AdminConfig',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'world',
)
```

As the tutorial teaches.
Does anyone has an idea of what might be happening?

I have already uninstalled Django 1.6.1 and installed again.
Thanks

Comment: which version of django ?

Comment: I am only using 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

You are not following the tutorial which matches the version of Django you have installed. `'django.contrib.admin.apps.AdminConfig'` is only available on master (1.7dev).